# Who is the Rebbe that will redeem us in the maamer bosi legani by the Lubavitcher Rebbe?

Tags: chabad

After more than ten years I managed to find a copy of the maamer given by the Lubavitcher Rebbe Menachem Mendel Schneerson. The conclusion of the maamer talks about seeing the Rebbe in the flesh and him redeeming us. In the the immediate context he talks about the Rebbe Rayats his father in law. But in the greater context he talks about the seventh generation completing the work of the first generation. He himself was the seventh generation from the first Lubavitcher Rebbe Shneur Zalman. So now I am confused. Who is the Rebbe that will redeem us? Him or his father in law? If he is talking about his father in law was he then counting the generations from the Baal Shem Tov?

Comment: Basi Legani is a series of ma'amarim. They are distinguished by their year. What year are you talking about?

Comment: @RabbiKaii https://www.basilgani.com/_files/ugd/bbaaca_7b2a640b268b48078abe55dd711533f9.pdf

Comment: Do you mean: "And my revered father-in-law, the Rebbe, who "bore our ailments and carried our pains"?

Comment: The critics of the Rebbe would definitely say he meant himself.